# MS-Access, OleDbCommand, Getting a "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm having trouble because I'm very rusty with using OleDb with Microsoft access.  I add parameters to the command, and execute the query and I get "No value given for one or more required parameters."

```
void LoadPositions(string accountKey, IEnumerable<Positions> positions)
{
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("delete from AccountPositions where BrokerAccountKey=?", conn, tran);
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = brokerAccountKey;
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I'm at my wits' end... help somebody!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seem to recall that MS Access requires a "DELETE * FROM ..." syntax. The * isn't standard SQL, but I think Access requires it. Also, I've had better luck with `cmd1.Parameters.Add( new OleDbParameter(...` syntax. It should be the same, but at least it's something different to try.

Comment: @Charlie Kilian Nope, DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID=1 just worked fine.  I thought that may have beent he issue too, so no worries :P

Comment: I see that your parameter is named `accountKey` but you are using `brokerAccountKey`. This might just be because you've cut down your example code for your SO example, but it might be because you have brokerAccountKey declared somewhere else. Might that be the issue?  UPDATE: Chris Buckler's comment below looks promising.

Comment: Of note, @Charlie, they are functionally equivalent, and I have tried it your way too.

All the documentation indicates simple "?" question marks in the queries, and simple parameter ordering for setting values.  It just doesn't seem to be working!  Any other suggestions?

Comment: This is the problem, I had actually cut down the code, and further down the commandtext was being modified to have a field with dashes but wasn't wrapped in the [] notation.  Very difficult via the error messages to discern that, but with some of your suggestions I stumbled upon the solution.

Comment: I'm going to vote to remove this post because I don't feel it helps diagnose this error properly due to my mishandling of it.  THANKS TO ALL with your help, I really appreciate the suggestions!

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but is AccountPositions a table? If it's an MS Access query, the query itself can cause that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"delete * from AccountPositions where BrokerAccountKey=@variableName"
```

I think you need to add the @ for your parameters if I remember correctly for access.

It's not liking you using the ? for variable name.  I just tried this out and it works fine.

**EDIT *****

Try defining your parameters a little different.

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variableName", txtSomeValue.text);
```

Just make sure that txtSomeValue.text is the same value as what you have defined in the access db.

If none of this works, then most likely "brokerAccountKey" is actually undefined when access is trying to commit the query.

Comment: Sorry @chris, but that generates a syntax error: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"

Comment: @enorl76 I believe it was because you were using the question mark.  Try it out again because I tested this and it is working.  Good luck friend!

Comment: @chris, you realize this is MS-Access right?  That does work for SQL Server.  I just tried it and no workie  :(

Comment: I just opened MS access, copied and pasted the above SQL into ms access and it works perfectly fine.. This tells us that its not the select that is your problem lol. I literally copy and paste this code into c# frontend and it still works fine.  I'll edit my answer and see if we can narrow down the problem for you...

Comment: I trust your answer, as I notated above there was a cut-n-paste problem.

Comment: Glad you solved it!  If you need any help diagnosing, feel free to shoot me a message.  Love messing around with sql & c# :)